# Break an infinite loop

Tags: java, events, loops, break

i have an infinite loop something like that:

```
while(true) {
    //do something
}
```

I would like to be able to break the loop using a key for exaple escape key. I think it could be done using events but as i am new to java i cant do that. 
Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

In the while loop the program reads a value from usb and then send it over the network using sockets. My program is the server and sends bytes to a client. I want to be able to stop that server with a key!

---

In the while loop the program reads a value from usb and then send it over the network using sockets. My program is the server and sends bytes to a client. I want to be able to stop that server with a key!

Comment: More details are needed. Is it a console application? Can you post some code?

Comment: the question is quite some ambiguous, more details are needed

Answer (score 3):

Pure java, by itself, does not have a notion of a key input. You usually get them from a specific IO module (e.g., console based, AWT based, Swing based, etc.).

You would then check for the condition or break.
If your notification of a press is asynchronous, you would probably set some flag (e.g., breakRequested), and check for this flag and break if it has changed.

For Console access, take a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html 
but pay attention to the many questions about this facility here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: "Pure java, by itself, does not have a notion of a key input" -- then you list Java core libs that can be used to do just that

Answer (score 3):

Use the `break` keyword.  For example:

```
try {
  Console console = new Console();
  while(true)
  {
    String input = console.readLine();
    if("quit".equals(input))
    {
       break;
    }
    // otherwise do stuff with input
 }
catch(IOException e)
{
  // handle e
}
```

Many programmers think the following would be more readable:

```
try
{
  Console console = new Console();
  for(String input = console.readLine(); !"quit".equals(input); input = console.readLine())
  {
     // do stuff with input
  }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
  // handle e
}
```

Comment: @org.life.java - ugh, been doing other languages too much lately, thanks & fixed

Comment: @Qwerky - I don't think I quite understand what you are getting at - what would be the problem with a blocking statement?

Comment: He wants his app to run continuously until the user presses escape. If you introduce a blocking statement then the user will have to stay at the keyboard pressing enter every time he wants the loop to be executed. If the user loses his concentration or stops paying attention then the app is going to hang.

Comment: @Qwerky - I was simply trying to illustrate getting input until a break was used, since there wasn't much to go on in terms of the app, but you make an excellent point.

Answer (score 1):

change while(true) to something like while(!isStopped()){...}

Comment: This solution is much better than using a "flag" variable.  For one, your method name can be intention revealing, and also you can separate your "should I stop" from the logic in the loop.

Comment: Note that the solution implies that the condition/state should be on the heap (unless checking something like System.currentTimeMillis()), which, baring a very simple program, should be the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, while your application is in that block, and is spinning, no other portion of your application will be able to process instructions.  That is unless you spin off your worker process into a new thread and share a variable/flag between the two.   That way, when a key is pressed, through whatever means you have in capturing it, you can modify a boolean variable which will carry over to your thread.  So you can set your loop up like the following:

```
while(_flag) 
{
   //Spin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this program that terminates an infinite loop if a specific key is pressed:

```
class terminator {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {
        char press, clear;

        for(;;) {
            System.out.print("Press any key to get display, otherwise press t to terminate:  ");
            press = (char)System.in.read();

            System.out.println("You Pressed: "+ press);

            do {
                clear = (char)System.in.read();
            } while(clear != '\n');
            System.out.println("\n");
            if (press=='t'|press=='T') {
                System.out.println("Terminating Program......Program Terminated!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To break infinite loop with a condition.

public class WhileInf {

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int i = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (i == 10) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Hello");
        i++;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can force quit the console if you are in infinite loops.
Window = Ctrl + Shift + Esc
Mac = Option + Command + Esc

Answer (score -2):

```
while(true)
{
   if(   )
   {
        break;
   }
   else if()
   {
        break;
   }
   else
   {
        do something;
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: User asks: "I would like to be able to break the loop using a key for exaple escape key". This does not answer that question.

Comment: I agreed with @TomasVinter